# How can I insert a blank space (" "), when I concatenate a string?

Tags: c#, java

This question is for C Sharp (and Java maybe :).

When I want to display a message to the console, I want to insert after each "+" a blank space. How can I do this, without inserting manually that blank space?

Comment: How are you displaying the message? Some code, and an example of the expected output would be _amazingly_ helpful.

Answer (score 18):

try this

```
var text = string.Join(" ", new[] {foo, bar, other });
```

Comment: you don't need to explicitly create the array in code. The join-method takes a params string[] argument, which will tell the compiler that string.Join(" ", foo, bar, other); is perfectly fine. A bit easier to read IMO :)

Answer (score 7):

You can't, really - just put it in explicitly:

```
Console.WriteLine(foo + " " + bar);
```

or

```
System.out.println(foo + " " + bar);
```

I mean you *could* write a method with a parameter array / varargs parameter, e.g. (C#)

```
public void WriteToConsole(params object[] values)
{
    string separator = "";
    foreach (object value in values)
    {
        Console.Write(separator);
        separator = " ";
        Console.Write(value);
    }
}
```

... but personally I wouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

if you're looking for a way to tidy your printing routine try `String.Format` e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", string1, string2));
```

Answer (score 6):

[In C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string.Join(" ", "Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
```

[In Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-):

```
String.join(" ", "Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
```

Each of these methods permits a variable number of strings to join, and each has various overloads to pass in collections of strings too.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace "+" with "+ ". Something like this:

```
new String("Foo+Bar").replace("+", "+ ");
```

Comment: I think the "+" is meant to be a plus *in code*. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: If it is, then your answer is the correct one obviously.. The question itself is a little unclear though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a concatenation of strings or just a '+' character? In Java, if there are lot of parameters to show within an output string you can use `String.format` method like this: `String.format("First: %s, second: %s, third: %s etc", param1, param2, param3)`. In my opinion it's more readable than chained concatenation with '+' operator.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use String Interpolation as well using the `$` special character, which identifies a string literal as an interpolated string

```
string text1 = "Hello";
string text2 = "World!";
Console.WriteLine($"{text1}, {text2}");
```

Output

```
Hello, World!
```

**From Docs**

String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to create formatted strings than a string composite formatting feature.

```
// Composite formatting:
Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}! Today is {1}, it's {2:HH:mm} now.", name, date.DayOfWeek, date);

// String interpolation:
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}! Today is {date.DayOfWeek}, it's {date:HH:mm} now.");
```

Both calls produce the same output that is similar to:

```
Hello, Mark! Today is Wednesday, it's 19:40 now.
```

Answer (score -1):

Or in Java you can use the `printf` variant of `System.out`:

```
System.out.printf("%s %s", foo, bar);
```

Remember to put in a "`\n`" [line feed] at the end, if there are multiple lines to print.